# How to make an automated test on a domReady javascript

Tags: jquery, linux, coffeescript, automated-tests, functional-testing

My script starts working only after every script is loaded and the DOM is ready. I want to write a functional test for it.

I'm using Linux. I wrote a test using [Lotte](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/lotte), CoffeeScript and PhantomJS.
It's good, it works but it does not wait for the DOM to load.
(`setTimeout` doesn't work as it says in the example)

I don't use AngularJS or any frameworks except jQuery.
The application is 100% client-side, no `npm` or anything.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: um, I know about this, I already use it. I want to combine it with automated testing.